# Mostrar Valor total do pedido na View asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Eu tenho uma View Index onde vou mostrar o nome do armazem o total de pedido e somar todos pedidos e mostrar o valor total.Eu criei um RelatorioArmazem. Eu consigo pegar o total de pedidos. Na minha tabela ele ja está certo com o valor total  corrreto, mas na view o valor total ele só traz o valor avulso de um produto.

```
    public class RelatorioArmazem
{
    [Key]
    public int relatorioId { get; set; }
    public int ArmazemId { get; set; }
    public decimal valor { get; set; }
    public decimal valorTotal { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int totalPedido { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ArmazemId")]
    public virtual Armazem Armazem { get; set; }
}
```

Armazem

```
    public class Armazem
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public int Prazo { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Deposito> Deposito { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<RelatorioArmazem> RelatorioDetalhes { get; set; }
}
```

Minha View

```html
@model IEnumerable<ABC.Models.Data.Armazem>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
        </th>
        <th>
            Total Pedido
        </th>
        <th>
            R$ Total
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RelatorioDetalhes.Count)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RelatorioDetalhes.FirstOrDefault().valor)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Armazem.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var ra = db.RelatorioArmazemDetalhes.Where(x => x.ArmazemId == id).ToList() ;
        var total = ra.Sum(x => x.valor);
        RelatorioArmazem arm = new RelatorioArmazem();
        foreach (var item in ra)
        {

            arm.totalPedido = ra.Count;
            arm.valor = item.valor;
            arm.valorTotal = total;
            arm.Nome = item.Nome;
            ViewBag.ValorTotal = total;
        }

        return View(arm);
    }
```

Comment: não seria somente trocar item.RelatorioDetalhes.FirstOrDefault().valor por item.RelatorioDetalhes.FirstOrDefault().totalPedido ?

Comment: isso só pega total de pedidos,  a variavel valorTotal recebe  a soma de todos pedidos isso eu consigo mostrar na view de detalhes, mas na view index não

Comment: como está o código no Controller ?!

Comment: @ JcSain coloquei pra voce ver, na view detalhes eu consigo ver valor total, na view index não

Comment: Tire esse trecho de código  ViewBag.ValorTotal = total; de dentro do laço, usa uma variável para acumular o valor total e depois fora do laço, use a ViewBag e na View recupere-a usando @ViewBag.ValorTotal

Comment: @ JcSaint essa view que vc fala é da detalhes la está tudo certo eu ja retirei esse viewbag de lá, o problema na  Controller Index, eu não consigo pegar o mesmo valortotal que está na controlerdetalhes e mostra na view Index

Comment: @CesarAugusto, você pode passar o valor total pela ViewBag, similar ao que tu fez no Detail, ou na view `Model.Sum(m => m.RelatorioDetalhes.Sum(r => r.valorTotal))` e se o problema for na tabela da view que postou, você substitui o `item.RelatorioDetalhes.FirstOrDefault().valor` por `item.RelatorioDetalhes.Sum(v => v.valor)`

Comment: @ KelvynRisso  Cara se se eu pudesse te paga uma caixa de cerveja agora, muito obrigado, funcionou exatamente como eu queria